# Second interview process for a company that I've previously turned down an offer from?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, hiring-process

Last year I interviewed with a company (a relatively small software company) that I thought was a great fit, but had to turn down the offer due to family matters.

Now I'd like to try applying to this company again, but I'm wondering if it's the norm to go through a full or partial interview process a second time?

I'm not particularly gifted in terms of the technical screens and I needed every bit of prep the first time around.

As such, It'd really help to know if other people have had to go through a second set of interviews, since I could take that into consideration and prep significantly before contacting them.

Thanks!

Comment: Off topic, I'm afraid - we can't tell you what a specific company is going to do.

Comment: Understood, feel free to delete the question.

Comment: I don't think your problem is the technical screen, You passed it once (how did you get the offer the first time?). However, I think you need to explain to them why you turned down the offer last year. Family matters is not enough, I am afraid.

Answer (score 3):

Some companies would start from the beginning, others would shorten the process. There's no way to know how this particular company will handle your interview process, should you be granted one.

Simply prepare as if this were a new company and you'll be covered either way.

Additionally, make sure you have a very good story why this time will be different and you won't turn down an offer. The company will likely be wary regarding that.